# Update Record Type of a custom object using trigger

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I'm unable to update record type of a custom object.

Other fields are getting updated but not Record Type

Please help

Here is my code,

```
trigger UpdateRecordType on ZI_Quote__c (before Update) {

    List<ZI_Quote__c> ZIQuotes = new List<ZI_Quote__c>();
    Map<String,ID> RecordTypeMAP = new Map<String, Id>();
    for (RecordType RecType: [Select Id, DeveloperName from RecordType where sObjectType ='ZI_Quote__c']){
        RecordTypeMAP.put(RecType.DeveloperName, RecType.id);
    }

    For(ZI_Quote__c ZIQ : trigger.new){

        IF (ZIQ.Hours_Remaining__c <= 0 && ZIQ.Status__c == 'Received From Supplier'){
            ZIQ.RecordTypeID = RecordTypeMAP.get('Remaining hr');
            ZIQuotes.add(ZIQ);
        }
        Else IF(ZIQ.Hours_Remaining__c <= 0 && ZIQ.Status__c == 'Submitted To Supplier'){
            ZIQ.Buyer_Name__c= 'TEST';
            ZIQ.RecordTypeid = RecordTypeMAP.get('Before 48 hr remaining time');
            ZIQuotes.add(ZIQ);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using wrong names to retrieve the Id of the record type.

I would assume that the `DeveloperName` for **Before 48 hr remaining time** would be **Before_48_hr_remaining_time**.

Note that `DeveloperName` can not have any spaces in it, so you are most likely using just a normal `Name` field of the `RecordType`, and not `DeveloperName`

And because you're tying to get something from a `Map` which doesn't have a valid key, the `Map` will just return `null`, so your `RecordTypeID` will always be `null`

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the **DeveloperName** of the record types as the key to your map.

but when you are retrieving the value from the map, you are using the **record type label** instead of the Developer Name.

usually the developer name will have **underscores instead of spaces**.

so use the **developer names as keys** when retrieving the record type id from the map.